# Outer Join with sqlalchemy (ORM)

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am trying to do a `relationship()` with an OUTER JOIN so that it joins the second table if there is something to join it with.  I am currently stuck on how to do this though, I cannot seem to figure out the right combination of `options()`, `relationship()` and `outerjoin()`.

I have the following tables and I am trying to join AppLike to Application if a row exists with the Application ID AND the artistID (which is provided by the function)

Happy to provide any additional information, I already have one of my joins working as you can see below, but there will always be a row to match for that one.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from . import Base
from . import DBSession
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import (
    INTEGER,
    VARCHAR,
    TEXT,
    TINYINT,
    )
from sqlalchemy.sql import and_
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, joinedload
import time

# 0 = new
# 1 = Denied
# 2 = Accepted
def getNewApplications(artistID):
    query =  DBSession.query(Application).\
        options(joinedload('pieces')).\
        options(joinedload('vote')).\
        filter(AppLike.artist_id==artistID).\
        filter(Application.approved==0)
        #join(AppPiece, Application.app_id==AppPiece.app_id).\

        #outerjoin(AppLike, and_(Application.app_id==AppLike.app_id,
        #    AppLike.artist_id==artistID)).\

    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    return query.all()    

class Application(Base):
    """ The SQLAlchemy declarative model class for a FileFavorite object. """
    __tablename__ = 'applications'
    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
        'mysql_charset': 'utf8'
    }

    app_id = Column(INTEGER(11), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(64), nullable=False)
    nickname = Column(VARCHAR(64), nullable=False)
    email = Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)
    description = Column(TEXT(), nullable=False)
    profile_link = Column(VARCHAR(128), nullable=False)
    location = Column(VARCHAR(64), nullable=False)
    approved = Column(TINYINT(4), nullable=False)
    pieces = relationship("AppPiece", lazy='joined')
    vote = relationship("AppLike", lazy='joined')

    def __init__(self, name, nickname, email, desc, profileLink,
                 location, approved):
        self.name = name
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.email = email
        self.description = desc
        self.profile_link = profileLink
        self.location = location
        self.approved = approved

class AppPiece(Base):
    """ The SQLAlchemy declarative model class for a FileFavorite object. """
    __tablename__ = 'app_pieces'
    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
        'mysql_charset': 'utf8'
    }

    app_piece_id = Column(INTEGER(11), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    app_id = Column(INTEGER(11), ForeignKey('applications.app_id'))
    link = Column(VARCHAR(128), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, appID, link):
        self.app_id = appID
        self.link = link

class AppLike(Base):
    """ The SQLAlchemy declarative model class for a FileFavorite object. """
    __tablename__ = 'app_likes'
    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
        'mysql_charset': 'utf8'
    }

    app_id = Column(INTEGER(11), ForeignKey('applications.app_id'))
    artist_id = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    vote = Column(TINYINT(4), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, appID, artistID, vote):
        self.app_id = appID
        self.artist_id = artistID
        self.vote = vote
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely don't need `options(joinedload('pieces'))`, it is already defined in your models (`lazy='joined'`). The join condition is the tricky part here and needs to be done using subquery, since we want to filter there as well. So, the final query should look something like this:

```
# We do the filtering on AppLike in the subquery and later join
# Application to it.
applike_subq = DBSession.query(AppLike).\
    filter(AppLike.artist_id == artistID).subquery()
query = DBSession.query(Application).\
    outerjoin(applike_subq, Application.vote).\
    filter(Application.approved == 0).all()
```

Comment: Hi.  Using the query you provided I am getting [] back as a result since in this case there is no `AppLike` to join (since no such record exists).  I need to make sure that I am still getting a result back if there is no `AppLike` that matches and would leave `Application.vote = None`  Do I need to change how the `relationship()'s` are set up?

Comment: There will always be a many-to-one relationship between AppPieces and Application and a many-to-one relationship between AppLike and Application but when querying only one possible AppLike will be matched based on the artistID, or none may be matched if there isn't a record in AppLike that matches.  Thanks, gonna read up on joins right now.

Comment: Well, I guess I misunderstood your requirements for the query. If what you really meant was `OUTER JOIN`, then simply change `join()` to `outerjoin()` in the query from my answer.

Comment: Hi, with this new query I am not even getting anything, just [] as I was before.  I feel like the `options()` is needed in order to get this data properly?

Comment: No, `options()` has nothing to do with this. I feel that the problem lies in a `filter()` part which uses `AppLike` model, and that makes it required even if we're using `outerjoin()`. I checked SA docs on `join()` and believe that I can write the correct query. Will update my answer to write it there.

Comment: Sweet, this works! :D  Thanks so much, guess i have to do subqueries for these outerjoins to work properly, now I have it all setup and can finally continue working on this project..been stuck for a day now lol.